# z-index preventing scroll box from working in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to create a kind of LinkedIN look where the profile photo sits on half of the cover photo and half of the text/paragraph box below (I think it looks cool) but when I achieve this the scroll box stops working. I've tried zline and relative and absolute but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance, been stuck on this for day or two now.

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* The six dividing sections ------  */

html, body {height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0%; margin: 0%;}

div {width: 100%; height: 100%;}

#div2 {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
}


/* main classes --------------  */

.lawyer-header {
  color: black;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 65px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

/* THREE CLASSES, Cover, Profile, scroll box  */


.ryan-profile {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #d9d9d9;
  display: block;
  /* top: 50%;
  left: 50%; */
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
}

.cover-photo1 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width:800px;
  height:200px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
}
.p-one {
  width:800px;
  height:255px;
  border-style: outset;
  text-align: justify;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  box-shadow:10px 10px 2.5px #d9d9d9;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height:1.5em;
  border:6px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}



</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">



<body>
<div id="div2">
  <section>
    <h1 id="about" class="lawyer-header">Lawyer Turned Developer</h1>

  <div>
    <img class="cover-photo1" src="images/cover-photo1.jpg" alt="Cover Photo">
  </div>

    <div class="profile-pic-class">
      <img class="ryan-profile" src="images/ryan-profile.jpg" alt"Photo of Ryan McAvoy, Developer">
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-box1">
      <figure class="p-one">
      <p>After successfully completing a Degree and Masters Degree in Law, I began searching for a job within
        the legal industry. Unfortunately (later found to be fortunate), this proved to be very difficult. Having
         some previous sales experience, I decided to accept recruitment job offer with Mortimer Spinks. At
         the time, I did not know what recruitment entailed nor did I know anything about the industry I was
        soon to be recruiting in, technology.</p>
      <p>Working as a recruiter was an eye-opening experience into the world of technology. It was only
         through working at Mortimer Spinks I began to realise how much technology is integrated into our
         daily lives. Moreover, I discovered the depth of work required to develop such technologies. </p>
      <p>The part I most enjoyed about recruitment was meeting with developers and talking about the latest
         technologies and their personal projects. I’ve always been quite entrepreneurial and once I
         discovered the capabilities of technology, I began coming up with solutions to everyday problems.
         Naturally, I did not have the skills or finance to build these ideas; having worked in recruitment I
         know how expensive building websites and apps can be. I also thought given my age (26 at the time),
         it would be too late to learn how to code. I decided to put these ideas to the back of my brain and
        focus on my career instead. </p>
      <p>Eventually, I managed secure a paralegal position within a highly respectable law firm which has
         been involved in some of England’s most notable cases in the last 30 years. I enjoy my current job
         and still like law however, these ideas are still festering at the back of my brain. I have considered
         the possibility of becoming a solicitor and then using the money from that to fund the various ideas.
         It was at this point I thought, why not become a developer yourself. I’m extremely passionate about
         technology and really believe, if not already, the tech industry is the future. Why not work as a
         developer, learn the required skills and network with the people within the industry I wish to one
         day establish my business. It does not make sense to have a career in law with the knowledge that in
         five years time I plan to establish a business within a completely different industry. </p>
      </figure>
</body>
</html>
﻿
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I didn't misunderstand your goal with this question, so please let me know if I did.

Anyways, to raise the profile picture, you just need to center it using `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto`, then raise it into the element above using `margin-top`. The value of `margin-top` would be 50% of the height of your profile picture multiplied by -1.

I also adjusted your cover photo a bit by setting it as the `background-image` of a `<div>` that contained your header text. This fixed the margin beneath the cover photo.

```css
  text-align: center;* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* The six dividing sections ------  */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#div2 {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
}


/* main classes --------------  */



/* THREE CLASSES, Cover, Profile, scroll box  */

.ryan-profile {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #d9d9d9;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}

.cover-photo1 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
}

.p-one {
  width: 800px;
  height: 255px;
  border-style: outset;
  text-align: justify;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 2.5px #d9d9d9;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  border: 6px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}


/* ===== New ===== */

.profile-pic-class img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: -75px;
  /* Raise your profile picture by 50% of your profile picture's height */
}

.cover-photo {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.britannica.com/08/100608-004-B89F31B2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.cover-photo h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 65px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div2">
  <section>
    <div class="cover-photo">
      <h1 id="about" class="lawyer-header">Lawyer Turned Developer</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="profile-pic-class">
      <img class="ryan-profile" src="images/ryan-profile.jpg" alt "Photo of Ryan McAvoy, Developer">
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-box1">
      <figure class="p-one">
        <p>After successfully completing a Degree and Masters Degree in Law, I began searching for a job within the legal industry. Unfortunately (later found to be fortunate), this proved to be very difficult. Having some previous sales experience, I decided
          to accept recruitment job offer with Mortimer Spinks. At the time, I did not know what recruitment entailed nor did I know anything about the industry I was soon to be recruiting in, technology.</p>
        <p>Working as a recruiter was an eye-opening experience into the world of technology. It was only through working at Mortimer Spinks I began to realise how much technology is integrated into our daily lives. Moreover, I discovered the depth of work
          required to develop such technologies. </p>
        <p>The part I most enjoyed about recruitment was meeting with developers and talking about the latest technologies and their personal projects. I’ve always been quite entrepreneurial and once I discovered the capabilities of technology, I began coming
          up with solutions to everyday problems. Naturally, I did not have the skills or finance to build these ideas; having worked in recruitment I know how expensive building websites and apps can be. I also thought given my age (26 at the time),
          it would be too late to learn how to code. I decided to put these ideas to the back of my brain and focus on my career instead. </p>
        <p>Eventually, I managed secure a paralegal position within a highly respectable law firm which has been involved in some of England’s most notable cases in the last 30 years. I enjoy my current job and still like law however, these ideas are still
          festering at the back of my brain. I have considered the possibility of becoming a solicitor and then using the money from that to fund the various ideas. It was at this point I thought, why not become a developer yourself. I’m extremely passionate
          about technology and really believe, if not already, the tech industry is the future. Why not work as a developer, learn the required skills and network with the people within the industry I wish to one day establish my business. It does not
          make sense to have a career in law with the knowledge that in five years time I plan to establish a business within a completely different industry. </p>
      </figure>
```

Comment: I want the paragraph/scroll box to be right underneath the cover photo (cactus). But I want the profile photo to stay exactly where it is (so overlapping both the cactus and the paragraph/scroll box. Also I need the scroll box to work. in both your and my example, the scroll box does not scroll. Thanks for having a go, not sure what i am asking for is possible with css.